# Set date and time without Admin priviledges using .NET?

Tags: c#, windows, datetime, set, clock

I have a program built in C# that reads an atomic clock to get the accurated time and date. The program functions at a glance with Admin priviledges.

But, due to some "company compliances", it must run now as an usual user, without Admin priviledges (even without the "Run as Administrator" option enabled). And using .NET functions to set the current date and time are not functioning anymore - Windows Vista and above only allow settings in clock if you´re running the application in Admin mode.

Searching of an answer, I found that MS really limited the change of the realtime clock only to Administrators.

What can I do to change the date/time of Windows for almost 3,500 users now?
I cannot change (nor create) priviledges based on Rules and anything like this.

Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE:** Even if using DLL calls within the code it´s impossible to set the Windows clock. I remind you all that change the program priviledges is not an option.

**Solution:** I see the only solution if distribute a command-line app set, via Manifest, to execute in Admin mode and provide a call from my original application to it.

Comment: Your app needs the SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME privilege

Comment: Really your question is not related to C#/.Net... Possibly superuser.com or serverfault.com would be better places to ask questions about adjusting/obtaining  Windows permissions. Additionally consider explaining why normal time service does not work for you if you decide to post on these other sites.

Comment: Linked [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964599/setting-the-time-programatically-in-windows-7) shows sample code and provides more detailed information on  SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME. Figuring out if/how to get that privilege to account that runs your program would be off-topic on SO.

Comment: I´m sorry, I guess I was not clear enough. The code is made in Visual Studio and I utilize .NET DATETIME function to set the date of Windows clock.  Thank you all for the help, I will see the duplicated link that hadn´t  appeared in *any* of my searches here. Thank you again.

Comment: .Net `DateTime` doesn't *have* any function for setting the clock - it can only read from it.

Comment: No Matt...  If you utilize *Datetime.Today* you set the Windows clock - but only if you have Administrator priviledges. That´s my problem and it´s a Windows Vista (and above) problem that neither .NET nor Assembly/DLL can solve. I had to build a commandline app and set it as Admin priviledged to get success in my problem. Anyway, thanks for your opinion.

Comment: I'm leaving closed because the question has no answer because it is a political question about privileges.