# Windows 7 time update

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a GUI developed in VB .net platform by which the user can set the system time. System is using Windows 7 platform. 
Recently I ran into a problem that the time cannot be updated using the GUI. Exiting the application and setting the clock directly through the windows is updating.

I have multiple systems like this and others are working fine with exactly the same application. Have checked the settings of the problametic system by comparing with other working systems and there is no difference. Have disabled the internet time sync also.

I am going clueless. Is there any idea what could be the cause or what further has to be checked ?

Comment: How are you changing the system time? So us some code

Comment: with the click of a button object directly assigning the written values in the box using system.time variable.

Comment: You must have in mind that setting the system time needs the calling process to have privileges. So, first try to run your application as Administrator and see if it works. Anyway, have a lok at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3964599/579895)

Comment: Simply describing your code won't do. If Pikoh's suggestions doesn't solve your problem then you must _**show us**_ your code.

Comment: Messing with the system time....eeek. You had better have a REALLY good reason to do that or you can cause no end of secondary issues.